# I want to create SOAP call in PHP to call XML and turn it into array

Tags: php, soap

This is my code:

```
<?php
$client = new SoapClient('http://opt.firmaac.ru:8080/wsdl/ITovars', 
array(
        'cache_wsdl'=>WSDL_CACHE_NONE,
        'trace'=>true,
     )
);       

$param = array();
$response = $client->GetGroups($param);

echo htmlentities($response);

$response = preg_replace("/(<\/?)(\w+):([^>]*>)/", "$1$2$3", $response);
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($response);
$body = $xml->xpath('//SBody')[0];
$array = json_decode(json_encode((array)$body), TRUE); 
print_r($array);
?>
```

However it return only string of that XML:
[image]

Any help would be appreciated.